# Playstation Now - Is there any way to use my PSN wallet only, instead of having to add a credit card info?

Tags: ps4, psn

Simply put, I live outside of North America so I've always been purchasing PSN cards to fund my NA account wallet and buy NA games. However, when I want to try out the seemingly excellent Playstation Now service to play PS3 games on my PS4, they demand a credit card info to start "free trial", even when I still have remaining money in my wallet and **don't really want this free trial whatsoever**. Is there no way to get around this? I've heard that virtual cards like Entropy don't work any more. Somebody said that applying an American Express card even if you're not in the US might work, but I doubt it. Do AMEX cards not have regions and street addresses etc.? This seems quite insane and frustrating. PS Now is not available in my region and I'm not sure it'll be available any time soon.

Comment: May I direct you to my question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370803/how-to-pass-age-verification-on-the-us-playstation-store-i-m-old-enough-but-h Maybe you know something.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind actually when the screen prompts you to enter credit card info you can just press "not now" and then you can choose to directly enter subscription without doing the trial.