# How to pass age verification on the US Playstation store? (I’m old enough, but how will I have to prove it?)

Tags: ps4, psn

I have a US-based “Playstation Network Account” on which I plan to buy a game via pre-paid PSN code “cards”.

I’m reluctant to add the money to the account, because I’m not sure how Sony will do the age verification for the game.—As a foreigner I might not have the documentation they expect!

I do remember seeing a German age verification in Germany (on the PS4), which accepted a German ID card (the numbers on it), but I don’t remember if that verification triggered because that PS4 was in Germany or because that PSN account was German...

Comment: are you in the US or somewhere else?

Comment: Somewhere else.

Comment: I think by default if you buy a voucher card the seller is supposed to verify your age. At least that's how it works in Germany. So if you use a voucher on your account you can buy any game you want. Not sure if the US store behaves in the same way.

Comment: @xji I just googled around and it seems that the 18+ recommendation on German PSN cards is not legally binding, so vendors can do what they want with it (some check, some don’t).

Answer (score 1):

US accounts do not seem to have age verification (at least not in this case). Voucher added value can buy rated content without further checking.—You can also test this with “free to play” content. It should trigger age verification for $0, but it doesn’t. I tried that with some titles, which clearly carried the same rating symbol as the game I was interested in (“M–Mature 17+”).

And it turns out that the ESRB-rating used in the US (and Canada, Mexico) is not legally binding for sale *in the US* according to Wikipedia ([rating comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_content_rating_system#Comparison_table) and [ESRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entertainment_Software_Rating_Board)).

Games in the highest rating “AO—Adults Only 18+” (the only ESRB-rating legally restricted in Canada and Mexico) are [not even “published by Playstation”](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/network/legal/ratings/) (if the link redirects to another region/language, replace wrong region manually with `en-us` in the URL).